# Request to reopen "what-is-bigger-a-squillion-or-a-kadgillion"

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51175/what-is-bigger-a-squillion-or-a-kadgillion

While this seems like (and may very well have been meant as) a silly nonsense question, there are serious things to say about **which "word" would *seem* larger to a native speaker** in direct comparison, in light of [sound symbolism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_symbolism) effects. Compare with the [bouba/kiki effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouba/kiki_effect), in which people consistently identify meanings of made-up words according to their sound values.

In particular, the English morpheme [*ka-*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ka-#English), a variant of [*ker-*](http://oed.com/view/Entry/102972), is "The first element in numerous onomatopœic or echoic formations intended to imitate the sound or the effect of the fall of some heavy body". This suggests an association with ponderous bulk.

In contrast, *squ-* /skw/ can be considered a [phonestheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonestheme) associated with small size: consider *squeak*, the sound of various small animals, and *squirrel*, a small rodent. Further, /i/ is cross-linguistically associated with small size.

Comment: Perhaps the question, if slightly better fleshed out, would be suitable for [linguistics.se], but I'm not entirely persuaded that it is on-topic here.

Comment: @waiwai933: If we interpret it as asking about English sound symbolism, as I suggest, that's no different from asking about how English speakers perceive the meaning of particular complete words; and that's clearly on-topic.

Comment: While I think your answer to the question is a good one, I agree very much with waiwai933; the question itself seems inadequately fleshed out.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to suggest an edit for the question?

Comment: As a native speaker, neither alternative seems inherently "bigger". Younger people tend to say *squillions*, "arty" Americans tend to say *kerjillions/kadgillions*, and I myself say *zillions*. On the other hand, it might help to know that *quintillions* are bigger than *quadrillions* if you get into some kind of "numerical pissing contest".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I’ve **never** heard either of  *kerjillions* or *kadgillions*.  Do people really say those?  I’m with you that *zillions* is by far the most common.  Sometimes you do hear *gazillions* or *gajillions*, though. I might be persuaded that *jillions* is also  heard.

Comment: @tchrist: I can't say for sure I've ever heard anyone use *kerjillions* in normal speech - it was new to me on the track *"My Eyes"* on Laurie Anderson's 1989 album *"Strange Angels"* - *And then **kerjillions** of stars start to shine \ And icy comets go whizzing by \ And everything's shaking with a strange delight \ And here it is:  the enormous night*. I may have seen it in comic books since, but can't even be sure about that. I don't remember hearing *gazillions/gajillions*, but then again I probably only remember Laurie Anserson's one because I really like the album (esp. her lyrics).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your verse-separating slashes have morphed into backslashes, doubtless under some sort of Microsoft corruption. Would would Bringhurst say? :)

Comment: I generally don't encounter numbers past trillion in common parlance. Everything past that either is expressed through chaining trillion or anything less, or through scientific notation. I'm not sure why we have words past trillion really. I mean, how many people can even grasp what the hell a billion of something is?

Comment: @shinyspoongod: there are enough examples of languages that don't have numbers beyond 10 to make us realize that they're all made up and it's just culture that will tell us if we need a definition for a bigger number. What's a peta-, exa- or yotta-byte? I know now but not a few years ago; those are in not uncommon use now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by FlumbleFingers, you cannot decide which word is used to mean something bigger than the other word means. There isn't a definitive answer to this, as people would probably give a slightly different meaning to those words. It also more probable that is a matter of a newer word versus an older word.